# Additional event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, handler

I have problem with second event handler. It's little complicated because i load my script to other page (i can't modify that page) and this script react to click event.
For example when I click on that client page any paragraph my script show me alert 'cliked'.
And it's works if that client hasn't his own click handler. When does my click function never run.

At this moment script is very simple:

```
jQuery('body').click(function(event){
  alert('clicked');
});
```

Any hint?
Sorry for my english.

Comment: the problem could be that the client is preventing the event propagation, in that case you might be out of luck

Comment: the element is also definitely ready when applying the event listener?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Form what I understood the client might be preventing the event propagation from elements where they have a click handler registered.

Since you are registering the event handler to the `body` element it will be fired only when the triggered in a particular element is propagated all the way upto the `body` element.

A dirty possible solution is to add the handler to all the elements in the page, but this will not work for elements which are added dynamically.

```
jQuery('body *').click(function(event){
  alert('clicked');
});
```

Demo: [Problem](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8mFX9/1/) (clicking on T1 does not fire the click event)
Demo: [Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8mFX9/2/)

Comment: @PiotrWójcik: Just beware that you're hooking `click` on a **lot** of elements. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder that why I said dirty solution ;( adding handler to every element in the document

Comment: @ArunPJohny: I figured. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder another possible solution will be to identify the elements which are preventing the propagation and target them instead of targeting all elements

Comment: OK, I spend some time with this 'body *' and this hooking many elements is a problem. I cant hook only one element.
@ArunPJohny can you give my any hint, how can I identify that preventing elemenets from other script ?

Comment: @PiotrWójcik another possible solution is to use event capturing as shown in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8mFX9/3/) but note that it works only with new browsers as given [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/DOM/elemento.addEventListener#Browser_Compatibility). Important: IE <9 not supported for those browsers you can go with the `body *` solution

Comment: @T.J.Crowder hi what is your opinion about the above solution

Comment: @ArunPJohny Thanks a lot. Works brilliant :)

Answer (score 0):

For bubbling events like `click`, handlers on elements get first chance at the event, and only then does it bubble up through the DOM tree to the ancestors like `body`. The handlers on the elements can *cancel* that bubbling via `event.stopPropagation()`. Typically they will if they handle the event.

You can't get the event ahead of the handlers the page attaches itself, at least not in any straight-forward way, because even if you attached your handlers to the actual elements, they're executed in the order they're attached, and so yours will be after the others. That's okay unless they use `event.stopImmediatePropagation()`, which stops even other handlers attached to the same element from being called.

An example helps: Let's look at this HTML:

```
<body>
   <div id="target">........</div>
</body>
```

and these handlers get attached in this order:

```
$("#target").click(function() {
    console.log("First direct handler");
});
$("#target").click(function() {
    console.log("Second direct handler");
});
$(document.body).click(function() {
    console.log("'body' handler");
});
```

If I click the `div`, we'll get this in the console: [Live Example](http://jsbin.com/adabod/1) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/adabod/1/edit)

```
First direct handler
Second direct handler
'body' handler
```

Now, let's change the first handler and leave the others the same:

```
$("#target").click(function(e) {
    console.log("First direct handler");
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Now a click gives us this:  [Live Example](http://jsbin.com/adabod/2) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/adabod/2/edit)

```
First direct handler
Second direct handler
```

The handler on `body` wasn't called because the first handler stopped propagation.

Let's change that first handler again:

```
$("#target").click(function(e) {
    console.log("First direct handler");
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```

Now a click gives us this:  [Live Example](http://jsbin.com/adabod/3) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/adabod/3/edit)

```
First direct handler
```

We didn't even get a call to the second handler, because the first handler stopped *immediate* propagation.

Comment: Thanks, for reach explanation :)